# IVT contents overwiting by writing at it's address

Tags: embedded, avr, interrupt-handling

in AVR the interrupt vector table (IVT) starts at address 0 in ROM, if we make our code start at address 0 by .ORG 0 ,will we overwrite the IVT contents and then reset and the other interrupts won't work properly  ?

Answer (score 2):

That is correct. If you don't have interrupts enabled, then it will not be a problem, just bad practice. The usual method is to start your program higher up in flash and make the instruction at 0 (the position of the reset vector) jump to your code. That way, you can add interrupt vectors later if you want.

Comment: when I wrote the code at address 0 all the interrupt didn't work except the reset button that did the reset operation properly and all the I/O registers cleared , how did it work despite the fact that the reset at address 0 doesn't point at the reset vector any more?

Comment: Each vector is at a location fixed by the hardware that is only 4 bytes long. That is only enough space for a jmp instruction. The reset vector usually just points to the start of your code. Since your code starts at 0, the jmp instruction was not necessary. Any other vector will be some spot near the beginning of your code, and not necessarily at the beginning of an instruction, either. (Instructions can be of various lengths, not just 4 bytes.) The vector will mostly likely contain nonsense for an instruction, as will every subsequent "instruction" that follows it.

Comment: @AliMak:  The hardware reset causes all registers to be set to their defaults including the program-counter to zero.  AVR's vector table is not a true vector table (which would contain just addresses), but rather hard-wired addresses to jump to on interrupt/exception.  To "emulate" a true vector table, the area is normally populated with JMP instructions.  On processors with a true IVT such as Cortex-M, this would not work; in the case of Cortex-M, address 0000h contains an initial stack-pointer value, and address 0004h the address at which to start execution -neither are instructions..